# Animate feDropShadow inside filter

Tags: html, svg, svg-filters, svg-animate

I have the following code and I want to animate `feDropShadow` inside `defs`

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300&display=swap");

*,
*::before,
*::after {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 position: relative;
}

html,
body {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

body {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}

:root {
 --easing: cubic-bezier(0.87, 0.08, 0.23, 0.91);
 --duration: 0.3s;
 --pink: #770946;
}

#app {
 height: 100vh;
 width: 100%;
 background: #1e0238;
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.circle-pink {
 transform: scale(1);
 fill: none;
 stroke: var(--pink);
 stroke-width: 6;
}

.circle-fill {
 transform: scale(1);
 transform-origin: center center;
 fill: var(--pink);
 stroke: none;
 stroke-width: 0;
 filter: url(#shadow);
}
```

```html
<div id='app'>
 <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <defs>
   <filter id="shadow">
    <feDropShadow id="shadow-appear" dx="-0.4" dy="0.4" stdDeviation="0.2" flood-opacity="0.25" />
   </filter>
   <animate xlink:href="shadow-appear" attributeName="dx" values="0;-0.4;0" dur="3s" />
   <animate xlink:href="shadow-appear" attributeName="dy" values="0;0.4;0" dur="3s" />
  </defs>
  <circle cx="50" cy="25" r="45" class="circle-pink" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="25" r="40" class="circle-pink" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="25" r="35" class="circle-pink" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="25" r="30" class="circle-pink" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="25" r="25" class="circle-pink" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="25" r="20" class="circle-pink" />
  <circle cx="50" cy="25" r="18" class="circle-pink circle-fill">
   <animate attributeName="r" values="18;20;18" dur="3s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
  </circle>
 </svg>
</div>
```

As per the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/feDropShadow#Attributes), these properties are animatable.

I want to achieve [this animation](https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/107759/screenshots/9661632/media/871bb418c1a1f6875cee221c96e7ed03.mp4) using only SVG.

The radius is animating, but not the shadow.

I couldn't find any decent docs regarding this as well.

**PS;** I have already tried [this pen](https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/dPRVqL) and it didn't work in my case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I have the following code and I want to animate feDropShadow inside
>   `defs`

To animate the feDropShadow filter, use the stdDeviation attribute

```
<feDropShadow id="shadow-appear" dx="-0.4" dy="0.4" stdDeviation="0" flood-opacity="0.25" >
         <animate attributeName="stdDeviation" values="0;4;0" dur="2s" 
              repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
</feDropShadow>
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300&display=swap");

*,
*::before,
*::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
}

html,
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}

:root {
    --easing: cubic-bezier(0.87, 0.08, 0.23, 0.91);
    --duration: 0.3s;
    --pink: #770946;
}

#app {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    background: #340362;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.circle-pink {
    transform: scale(1);
    fill: none;
    stroke: var(--pink);
    stroke-width: 6;
}

.circle-fill  {
    transform: scale(1);
    transform-origin: center center;
    fill: var(--pink);
    stroke: none;
    stroke-width: 0;
    filter: url(#shadow); 
}
```

```html
<div id='app'>
    <svg width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 -25 100 100">
        <defs>
            <filter id="shadow">
                <feDropShadow id="shadow-appear" dx="-0.4" dy="0.4" stdDeviation="0" flood-opacity="0.25" >
      <animate attributeName="stdDeviation" values="0;4;0" dur="2s" repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
    </feDropShadow>
            </filter>
             <animate xlink:href="#shadow-appear" attributeName="dx" values="0;-0.4;0" dur="2s" /> 
             <animate xlink:href="#shadow-appear" attributeName="dy" values="0;0.4;0" dur="2s" /> 
        </defs>
        <circle cx="50" cy="25" r="45" class="circle-pink" />
        <circle cx="50" cy="25" r="40" class="circle-pink" />
        <circle cx="50" cy="25" r="35" class="circle-pink" />
        <circle cx="50" cy="25" r="30" class="circle-pink" />
        <circle cx="50" cy="25" r="25" class="circle-pink" />
         <circle cx="50" cy="25" r="20" class="circle-pink" />
        <circle cx="50" cy="25" r="18" class="circle-pink circle-fill" >
             
        </circle>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured I used the wrong syntax. As per @Alexandr_TT answer. `animate` should be inside `feDropShadow`, not outside of it. After that you can animate any animatable property.

Comment: It doesn't have to be, you can use href or xlink:href to link to anything you want to animate.

Comment: It didn't work when I used `xlink:href`, but it worked when I moved `animate` inside `feDropShadow`

Comment: It should work: https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/animate.html#TargetElement are you still animating dx and dy?

Comment: Yeah, still animated those two attributes